# Checking the series $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)}+\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{b(b+1)(b+2)}-\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a,b >0$. I'm trying to find out if the following series is convergent:
$$
\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)}+\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{b(b+1)(b+2)}-\cdots
$$
I think the general form is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^i\frac{\prod_{j=0}^i\left(a+j\right)}{\prod_{j=0}^i\left(b+j\right)}
$$
But I'm not sure how to show that it converges. Will be glad for some guidelines.

Comment: Try with some examples. For example, you can see that when $a=b$, then the series becomes $1-1+1-1+...$ which does not converge. Try other examples, like $a=1$ and $b=2$, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation of the Gaussian hypergeometric series
$$
\begin{aligned}
-{_2F_1}(1,a,b,-1)-1%
&=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1)_k (a)_k}{(b)_k\, k!}(-1)^k\\
&=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)}+\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{b(b+1)(b+2)}-\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
which is absolutely convergent if $b-(a+1)>0$.  See [NIST DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.iii) for further details.

Comment: so if I take $a=1,b=1$ then the series is not convergent right?

Comment: The series will diverge but the hypergeometric function is defined by analytic continuation for those parameters.  In that case $_2F_1(1,6,4,-1)=31/80$.

Comment: Again, for $a=b=1$ the series does indeed diverge but by analytic continuation we have the result $_2F_1(1,1,1,-1)=1/2$.

Comment: [See here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/07/) for specific values involving integer parameters

Comment: Mor generally, if $a=b$ then the series is $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ which diverges.